# Download a Google Translate Pronunciation

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-translate

How do I download a pronunciation from Google Translation?

I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without any plugins or software. Any browser is capable of it. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQuZ7Pt_pA0) showing how to do it in **Microsoft Edge**. You can follow the same method with **Chrome**.

Comment: Please post the *answer* here, and include the link for reference.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the page and select "Inspect Element", then go to the network tab. Now, refresh the page with the network panel still open. Wait until nothing is showing up there anymore. While waiting, make sure not to get your mouse near the Listen button. Once nothing is showing up in the network panel, hover and click the listen button. As soon as you hover the listen button, an entry will appear that says "batchexecute". Find this entry. It should be above entries that say `log?format=json&hasfast=…`.

[image: chrome]
[image: firefox]

Click on that and then on the right select the "Response" tab. There should be a bunch of random characters that go off the screen very far to the right

[image]
[image]

Select just that text and copy it. The easiest way to do this is to scroll all the way to the right first and then click and hold to the right of the ending quotation mark, then move your mouse up to the line above, then move your mouse down to reach the starting quotation mark, holding the mouse the whole time.

Go to the console tab and type `v=` then paste then press enter. Then, paste this into the console and press enter

```js
{
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "data:audio/mp3;base64,"+JSON.parse(v)[0];
a.download = "file.mp3";
a.click();
}
```

The mp3 file will download.

Comment: Perfect and underappreciated solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Google search the word of which you want to download pronunciation
   by entering the query :"*How to pronounce *word**"
2. Right-click the page and click **View page source**.
3. Search for Mp3.
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuG3E.png)
4. click the mp3 link.
5. Click the 3 dots and click **Download**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the online [Listen App](http://ctrlq.org/listen/) to download Google pronunciation as MP3 audio files.

Comment: It's not working. The downloaded file is empty. Also, I couldn't find an option to download pronunciation from foreign languages.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me; after a bit of searching, I found a website called https://soundoftext.com/ that allows you to put in text, choose the language, and then be able to listen to and download the pronunciation. The voice is the exact same as Google Translate's -- hopefully this is helpful to anyone passing by this thread.